# Hook for taxonomies needed

Tags: taxonomy

I am a newbie and spent now hours to no avail on this, so I really hope you can help me out here. One thing ahead: I do **NOT** want a plugin for this. I need to just change the word 'Cusine' (cp_recipes_cuisine) to 'Language' and the words 'Cooking Method' (cp_recipes_cooking_method) to 'Country':

View: https://gofile.io/d/bXbISK

I need this for the plugin 'Cooked PRO', I made the stupid mistake to buy from Boxy Studio directly and not with a cheaper glp because I hoped to get support from them or suport on wordpress.org but they seem to be dead, the support section on wordpress.org was also last active two years ago... So I need help otherwise.

I tried [this hook](https://space-themes.com/how-to-change-a-custom-taxonomy-slug-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) in the functions.php, but didn't work:

```
function space_change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ){
    if( 'cp_recipes_cuisine' == $taxonomy ){ // Instead of the "old-slug", add current slug, which you want to change.
        remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
        $args['rewrite'] = array( 'slug' => 'cp_recipes_language' ); // Instead of the "new-slug", add a new slug name.
        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'space_change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args', 10, 3 );
```

Then I saw that in the plugin itself there is also a [taxonomy.php](https://gofile.io/d/KKVXgn), here I tried to replace 'cuisine/Cuisine' with 'language/Language' and same for the 'cooking method', but no success. I am out of any ideas what I can do in order to change this.... Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you trying to change the slugs or the labels or both? I don't think you want to call `remove_action` since you want that action to run every time, to update the registered `rewrite` arg.